# Blackbox testing using Arquillian

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jboss-arquillian, arquillian-drone

I am a QA person & do blackbox testing using `Java` + `TestNG` + `Selenium WebDriver` for our web application. I do not have access to the actual application code. My application runs on JBoss (in a remote server).

I heard about `Arquillian` recently & I saw some examples that they use `Arquillian + WebDriver`. When i googled, I could not get the exact use of Arquillian.

**Questions:**

- JUnit & TestNG are also unit testing frameworks. But I can use it for writing standalone blackbox testcases to test my application using `WebDriver`. Can this Arquillian also be used similarly?
- What features can it bring If i can use it in my existing TestNG framework? (for example, TestNG has parameter based testing, dependency support compared to JUnit).

Comment: Arquillian for automated blackbox testing http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-automation-using-arquillian-framework/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arquillian is NOT replacement for JUnit/TestNG, it is rather complementar - helps to manage lifecycle of the test and provides many useful extensions. In blackbox testing space, there are Graphene and Drone extensions.

I would encourage you to take a look at Graphene extension for Arquillian - these are focused on blackbox testing leveraging best practices such as Page Objects pattern:

https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-graphene

Graphene also tightly connects to Drone extension for Arquillian that helps to configure WebDriver.

Both tools builds on top of WebDriver, they don't replace it.

Comment: Is the deployment /  ShrinkWrap.create method mandatory? I keep asking this because all the examples have the method. Your answer does not clarify that. As i said, I do not have access to actual deploy-able code. It is like i am testing google.com search functionality & i do not work for google.